# Did I do right by adding "bitcoin" as a new tag to this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, editing

I just made the following edit: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20298

It adds the tag "bitcoin" to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33597/who-stole-the-bitcoins). One interesting feature of the puzzle is that you actually need to know how bitcoins work in order to finish solving the puzzle! As a result, I figured the new tag was appropriate because it indicates that specialized knowledge is required.

Was I correct in making this edit and creating this new tag?

Comment: There was no [tag:bitcoin] tag before you added it in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's anything *wrong* with it, but I wouldn't have added it. My guideline for when to add tags (which could be very different from other people's) is that they should be added when:

someone might reasonably want to either...

- see *only* puzzles with that topic, or
- filter out puzzles of that type.

A [bitcoin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) tag doesn't seem like it would be useful for either.

Comment: bitcoin and privacy related questions are becoming more popular across stack exchange. Although the number is small, I expect some people WILL use the bitcoin tag to search for puzzles in that category.

Comment: `bitcoin` is still an outlier as a topic of interest, and anyway it is a specific thing which can be easily found with a single-word search instead. For something requiring specific expertise that doesn't fit into a larger category, [tag:knowledge] is the way to go.

Comment: I would add a third reason to Deusovi's list: There are at least 3 (T.B.D.) questions which could use the tag. There is not much sense in creating a tag for a "group" which basically consists of a single member only. i.e. if it turns out that there are indeed *many* puzzles which would belong to "bitcoin" *then* I would consider adding the tag.